# How make raspberry pi web controls?

Tags: raspbian, php

I want to develop web based control software for the Pi in PHP. I have some experience in PHP , but i have experience in using PHP, but no experience in running it on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: your question appears to have nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi ... look for general programming tutorials and linux tutorials

Comment: @jsotola what you mean?

Comment: @jsotola I guess the actual question is "How to install a web server on the pi" and possibly something like "Can I control my Pi (e.g. GPIO) from PHP". This isn't really clear and maybe Goma01 Tera20 can add more details to the question.

Comment: @Goma01Tera20 you did not ask anything that is specific to RPi ... your question could easily apply to Linux, MacOS or Windows ... that makes it a general programming question ... you are "shooting yourself in the foot", if all you look for are RPi tutorials and RPi info on the web

Answer (score 2):

You can start off by setting up a simple apache server you can then use PHP for something like creating a dashboard that displays data from the sensors you connect to your Pi. I made a similar project for a high school hackathon last year.

Some tutorials to help you get started:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md
- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

welcome.

I assume you mean to ask: what do I need to make gpios and other pi-specific stuff usable in PHP?

I would encourage in using some other tech, but if that's your choice my gut feeling would be to just have some `system` calls, see [this example](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=219010).

The performance won't be exciting but it's acceptable for watering the pots or turning on a lamp.

A quick google of PHP libraries for GPIOs resulted in multiple matches, I wouldn't feel like using any but you can take the chance to experiment with them.